# How to check that new app.js file is available without refreshing page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application

I have SPA created with ReactJS and I need to check if new SPA version is released when current session is opened.

I mean if user open SPA with app.js?v=x and when we create the new release, a user should be informed about a release and will be asked to refresh the page.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks !

Comment: Please share the code if you have tried something so far.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).